# How do I free Giacco?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I've discovered Giacco rotting in the Dungeon under Raedric's Hold. He said the animancer had the key - which animancer, where?

Comment: I don't remember needing a key, I think I just picked the lock on his cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the animancer in the upper part of the same dungeon. She will drop the key on death, though I'm not sure if it can be obtained in other way.
[image]

Comment: Also, you can lock pick the door.